# Why is the relation in 3NF?

Tags: normalization, dependencies

> A relation is in 3NF (Third Normal Form) if it is in 2NF (Second Normal Form) and all the FDs (functional dependencies) in the relation are in the form X -> Y, where X is a superkey (a set of attributes that uniquely identifies a tuple in the relation) and Y is a non-prime attribute (an attribute that is not a part of the primary key).

```
SP (Sno, Sname, Pno, Qty)
```

Functional dependencies:

```
Sno, Pno -> Qty
Sname, Pno -> Qty
Sno -> Sname
Sname -> Sno
```

The candidate keys are Sno, Pno and Sname, Pno.

So the first 2 are in the form quoted above while the last two aren't. For instance in the case of `Sno -> Sname`, Sno is not a superkey and Sname is a prime attribute.

So why is the relation in 3NF?

Comment: Your "I have these FDs" doesn't make sense. "These are all the FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are some FDs that hold"?--Question can't be answered. Find out what a *cover* is & what the exact conditions are to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. And the set of all attributes must be given. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386492/3404097)

Comment: That definition is wrong. A correct definition in that style should mention trivial FDs & CKs & not PKs.

Comment: Your definition mentions a PK but your argument doesn't. So how can your argument be right? (Or clear.)

Comment: Your definition of 3NF is wrong - as philipxy already mentioned - plain and simple.

Comment: There are two definitions in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Comment: The 1st definition in the 3NF Wikipedia article section on definitions gives an incorrect definition of transitive FD. It should add that X, Y & Z are different sets. PS Find & follow some (good) published academic textbook(s) on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts or videos.) Dozens are online free in pdf & html.

Comment: what's the correct non-verbose definition of 3NF?